# Null object reference on Android app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, nullreferenceexception

Hi i am developing an app in android and i have attempt to invoke vitrual method on a null object reference in the Communicator.generateMessageId().

here is my code where the error occurs:

```
public class StatsActivity extends TaxiplonActivity {

protected Communicator comm;
protected TaxiMapGoogle messageId;
Message statusMessageBody;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.stats_activity);
    ToggleButton toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById (R.id.toggleButton1);

    // get action bar   
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();


    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setTitle("Driver Options");

    testRequest();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public void testRequest() {
    sendMessage(comm.generateMessageId(),"agent=driver&action=get&driverid=6609",
            OPTION_DRIVER, activityHandler,null);

    //System.out.println("MessageId: "+comm.generateMessageId());

}
@Override
public void postConnectionSuccessful() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void preConnectionReset() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

and here is the method i call from my communicator class:

```
public String generateMessageId() {

    try {
        TaxiplonApp taxiplonApp = (TaxiplonApp) parent
                .getApplicationContext();
        TwoFishEncryprion twoFishEncryprion = new TwoFishEncryprion(
                messageIdKey);
        String cleanMessageId = taxiplonApp.getDriverId() + "|"
                + taxiplonApp.getDeviceId() + "|"
                + ntpClock.getCachedDate().getTime();
        return twoFishEncryprion.encrypt(cleanMessageId).replace(" ", "");
    } catch (NTPClockException e) {
        AploonLogger.error("Problem generating imei messageId", e);
        parent.showNtpClockDialog();
    }

    return null;
}
```

I initiallize the comm in my TaxiplonActivity.class here :

```
  protected class Connector extends AsyncTask<Runnable, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        showBusyDialog();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Runnable... runnables) {
        //init communication
        comm = Communicator.getInstance(TaxiplonActivity.this, false);
        //if connection is already available, proceed to postConnectionInit (it will not be called, like when connection is established)
        if(comm.isConnected()) {
            postConnectionSuccessful();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        hideBusyDialog();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me how to fix this error?

Comment: where do you initialize `comm`?

Comment: Where is the initlialization for `comm`?

Comment: I updated my question to show you where i initiallize it

Comment: Post your logcat error here

Comment: You need to execute connector first and call testrequest()in postexecute method.

Answer (score 1):

Move this code from `doInBackground()` method

```
comm = Communicator.getInstance(TaxiplonActivity.this, false);
```

before

```
testRequest();
```

method.

Because your `testRequest()` executes before your `comm` initialize. So always you get `null` instance.

Comment: @PG See you after a long time ...+1 up

Comment: Thanks buddy. Same here. You can please come to chat room

Comment: This one http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93330/the-great-gujarati-android-developers-ever

Comment: when i move this code before testRequest() it gives me an error "No enclosing instance of the type TaxiplonActivity is accessible in scope"

Comment: This is because your activity extends with `TaxiplonActivity`. So you need to pass context of your `TaxiplonActivity` instead of `TaxiplonActivity.this`. Because it will give the context of your current class. In short its a context problem.

Comment: how should i fix this problem?

Comment: Simply pass the context of your current activity class. **StatsActivity.this**

Comment: i tried this comm = Communicator.getInstance(StatsActivity.this, false); but still not working

Comment: What is your TaxiplonActivity contains?

Comment: i initiallize the comm there as you can see in my question